# PowerMock: Is not an interface

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I am just trying to get PowerMock/EasyMock to work. I am using PowerMock 1.5:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-easymock-release-full</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my code:

```
    String text = PowerMock.createMock(String.class);
```

And that's it. When I run the program I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.String is not an interface`

I've tried doing:

```
    String text = EasyMock.createMock(String.class);
```

And using the RunWith annotation for PowerMock, but no matter what class I try, I always get this exception. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine with this version of EasyMock:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
  <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also take a look at how to mock system classes:

http://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/modules/module-test/mockito/junit4/src/test/java/samples/powermockito/junit4/system/SystemClassUserTest.java?spec=svn1714&r=1714

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I ask.... Using the wrong version of easymock. Needed to upgrade to version 3.0

Also String is a final class, so it doesn't work with string...

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock version less than 3.0 will throw this error. Upgrade you EasyMock version.